# gulp.dest with glob gulp.src - making it relative

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, cwd

I have a simple task in gulp that is supposed to transpile js:

```
function js() {
  return gulp.src('lib/modules/*/source/js/*.js')
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['@babel/env']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest((fileVinyl) => {
      return fileVinyl.path.replace('/source/', '/public/').replace(/[^\/]*js$/, '')
    }))
}

exports.default = gulp.parallel(js)
```

And I have a file structure like this:

```
lib
- modules
  - module1
    - source
      - js
        - file.js
  - module2
    - source
      - js
        - file.js
  - moduleN (...)
```

Now, I want it to create files like this:

```
lib
- modules
  - module1
    - public
      - js
        - file.js
    - source (...)
  - module2
    - public
      - js
        - file.js
    - source (...)
  - moduleN (...)
```

Of course, the code above doesn't work, it outputs files to folders like `lib/modules/module1/public/js/module1/source/js/`. Is there any method to force gulp to output the file to a specified path instead for it treating it like a base path for appending its own ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I had here was the wrong base for the file. But as I needed to change it dynamically, I couldn't just set it up in `src` options. Fortunately, I could change it easily in `dest` function, where I have the path available:

```
 .pipe(gulp.dest((fileVinyl) => {
      //changing the base so that it will include the whole path to the file,
      //excluding the filename
      fileVinyl.base = fileVinyl.path.replace(/[^\/]*js$/, '')

      //outputing the file to a /public/ folder instead of /source/,
      //keeping the structure
      return path.relative(process.cwd(), fileVinyl.path.replace('/source/', '/public/').replace(/[^\/]*js$/, ''))
    }))
```

Answer (score 1):

use the option `base` in gulp.src

like this:

```
gulp.src('your_file.js', {base: 'your_base_path'})
.pipe(/*...*/)
```

in your case, the `base` should be `lib/modules`

like this:

```
gulp.src('lib/modules/**/*.js', {base: 'lib/modules'})
.pipe(/*...*/)
.pipe(gulp.dest('lib/modules'))
```

this will create what you want:

```
lib
- modules
  - module1
    - public
      - js
        - file.js
```

This option tells gulp to ignore the base part of path and treat the rest of path as relative and hence replicate it in dest

Comment: Thank you, it looks like a good direction - the problem is the base is dynamic depending on which module it's processing, so for the first one it should be `{base: 'lib/modules/module1/public/js'}`, but after that it should become `{base: 'lib/modules/module2/public/js'}`.

Comment: @MichałSadowski I have edited my answer. please test it and tell me what happened

Comment: This, in turn, just overwrites original files - but I managed to crack it thanks to your input, I will post an answer in a second. Thank you!